# Check NSMakeRange is Able to take range or Not

Tags: iphone, nsrange

I am currently using the below code to take the substring

```
NSString *s1 = [stringName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

NSString *s2 = [stringName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(2, 4)];

NSString *s3 = [stringName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(6, [stringName length])];
```

Here, how to check the range is valid or not because i am not able to length of string to validate because it may differ on time. Please help me in this issue..

Answer (score 1):

For `s3`, you're starting at position and ask for exactly as many characters as there are in the string. But since you're starting at position 6, you're asking for 6 characters too many. You need to do:

```
NSString *s3 = [stringName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(6, [stringName length] - 6)];
```

Answer (score 1):

As the apple documentation says ..

**substringWithRange:**

Returns a string object containing the characters of the receiver that lie within a given range.

```
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange
```

**aRange**

```
A range. The range must not exceed the bounds of the receiver.
```

You need to check every time when you construct an NSMakeRange(), whether the Range you specified  within the length of your String OR not ... by Using some `if and else` condition